# Ansible parse_cli build object from config lines in arbitrary order

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to parse a DHCP scope from a range of Cisco IOS routers using Ansible.

**< TL;DR; >** I'm currently using parse_cli with a regex including multiple named matches for the same thing in different positions (e.g. `domain_name_1`, `domain_name_2`) then combining them in the output object by assigning them as `domain_name: "{{ item.domain_name_1 }}{{ item.domain_name_2 }}"` - as only one of them at a time will be populated, the output object still contains the correct data. I'd like to find a way to do it which doesn't require ugly inflexible hacks like that. **< /TL;DR; >**

I like the `parse_cli` Jinja filter as it provides a nice object as the output containing only the info I need, but I can't work out a way to have it cope with an arbitrary order of commands in the config.

Three examples of the same config in different order are as follows. Order of config lines can vary depending on which firmware version the router is running, the order the commands were entered in, or the model of router. The commands themselves (in this case) will always be the same so I just need a way to pull out each line and parse it appropriately.

**Cisco 867**

```
ip dhcp pool Data
  import all
  network 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
  update dns
  default-router 192.168.1.1
  dns-server 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8
  option 42 ip 192.168.1.1
  domain-name test.local
  lease 8
```

**Cisco 881**

```
ip dhcp pool Data
  import all
  network 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
  option 42 ip 192.168.1.1
  default-router 192.168.1.1
  dns-server 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8
  domain-name test.local
  lease 8
```

**Cisco 1111**

```
ip dhcp pool Data
  import all
  network 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
  default-router 192.168.1.1
  dns-server 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8
  domain-name test.local
  option 42 ip 192.168.1.1
  lease 8
```

In all of those cases or any other new order which appears in future, I want to create an object in ansible as a fact with format:

```
{
  "network": "192.168.1.0",
  "dns-servers": ["192.168.1.1", "8.8.8.8"],
  "domain-name": "test.local",
  "options": {
    "42": {
      "type": "ip",
      "value": "192.168.1.1"
    }
  }
}
```

Currently I'm doing something like this:

**tasks/main.yml**

```
- name: Get Cisco IOS DHCP pools
  ios_command:
    commands:
      - 'show running-config | s ip dhcp pool'
    retries: 1
  register: ciscoios_dhcp_pool_output

- name: Convert Cisco IOS DHCP pools to list
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  set_fact:
    info_dhcp_pools: "{{ ciscoios_dhcp_pool_output.stdout[0] | parse_cli('roles/get-router-dhcp-pools/parsers/ios-pools.yml') }}"
```

**parsers/ios-pools.yml**

```
---
vars:
  dhcp_pool:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    network: "{{ item.network_ip }}"
    subnet: "{{ item.network_subnet }}"
    dns_servers: "{{ item.dns_servers_1 }}{{ item.dns_servers_2 }}"
    domain_name: "{{ item.domain_name_0 }}{{ item.domain_name_1 }}{{ item.domain_name_2 }}{{ item.domain_name_3 }}"
    options: "{{ item.options_1 }}{{ item.options_2 }}"
    lease_days: "{{ item.lease_days }}"
    lease_hours: "{{ item.lease_hours }}"
    lease_minutes: "{{ item.lease_minutes }}"

keys:
  dhcp_pools:
    value: "{{ dhcp_pool }}"
    items: "^ip dhcp pool (?P<name>[^\\n]+)\\s+(?:import (?P<import_all>all)\\s*)?(?:network (?P<network_ip>[\\d.]+) (?P<network_subnet>[\\d.]+)?\\s*)?(?:update dns\\s*)?(?:host (?P<host_ip>[\\d.]+) (?P<host_subnet>[\\d.]+)\\s*)?(?:domain-name (?P<domain_name_0>[\\w._-]+)\\s+)?(?:default-router (?P<default_router>[\\d.]+)\\s*)?(?:dns-server (?P<dns_servers_1>(?:[\\d.]+ ?)+ ?)+\\s*)?(?:domain-name (?P<domain_name_1>[\\w._-]+)\\s+)?(?P<options_1>(?:option [^\\n]+\\n*\\s*)*)?(?:domain-name (?P<domain_name_2>[\\w._-]+)\\s+)?(?P<options_2>(?:option [^\\n]+\\n*\\s*)*)?(?:dns-server (?P<dns_servers_2>(?:[\\d.]+ ?)+ ?)+\\s*)?(?:domain-name (?P<domain_name_3>[\\w._-]+)\\s*)?(lease (?P<lease_days>\\d+)(?: (?P<lease_hours>\\d+))?(?: (?P<lease_minutes>\\d+))?\\s*)?(?:update arp)?"
```

That however feels very messy, and requires updates every time I discover a new order that config lines can appear in. It feels like the sort of thing that there should be a better way to achieve but I'm not sure on what it is.